# Azure Application Insights - AI (Internal): 24 message:"Missing required field specification

Tags: asp.net-mvc, npm, azure-application-insights

I have installed the front-end for azure application insights to track events on my application. My application uses web-pack for its front end. I cant see any event being tracked  when I use the NPM setup but everything works fine when I use the Snippet Setup.
The error I am getting in the browser is:

[image]
AI (Internal): 24 message:"Missing required field specification. The field is required but not present on source" props:"{field:exceptions,name:baseData}"

[image]

this is described in the documentation https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS#configuration

I am missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turned out that adding trackPageView method was the answer

```
import { ApplicationInsights } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web';
const appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
  config: {
    instrumentationKey: 'key',
  },
});
appInsights.loadAppInsights();
appInsights.trackPageView({});
```

Answer (score 2):

One place this can happen is when calling trackException with an exception variable that isn't an instanceof an Error, see: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/d3abfe4138d0cfd624f72288c14e73b0b4849f3b/shared/AppInsightsCommon/src/Telemetry/Exception.ts#L39

The documentation infers to do exception: new Error(...) and doing that fixes this issue.

One way you can reproduce this is if you do:

```
trackException({
  exception: error
})
```

where error could be something like:

```
{
  message: 'some error',
  stack: 'some stack'
}
```

Which is an object and not an instanceof an Error.

Comment: Correct answer!